# Como puedo denegar el acceso a archivos de carpeta publica en servidor apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, servidor

Intente poner un .htaccess en la raiz del proyecto de esta manera:

```
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|jpg|log|bak|txt)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
 Allow from 192.168.0.9
</FilesMatch>
```

Pero los archivos tmb se bloquean en el sistema y lo unico que quiero es que no se puedan accesar por medio de la barra de navegacion.

Comment: que archivos se bloquean? cuales queres bloquear?

Comment: Me explico, quiero denegar el acceso directo por URL a una carpeta con imagenes de caracter sensible, todas las imagenes son en formato jpg, lo que me lleva a utilizar el .htaccess para poder hacerlo, y funciona, pero deniego el acceso por url y tmb se restringe el acceso desde el sistema, osea las imagenes no se muestran en el sistema, necesito poder restringir el acceso directo, pero que se sigan mostrando por medio del sistema

Comment: podes bloquear el referrer en blanco o diferente al dominio pero esto se puede  falsear en una petición. que lenguaje muestra las imágenes? cómo obtienes el nombre de la imagen para mostrar? hay algún tipo de autentificación para acceder a la página que muestra las imágenes?